# how can i show php variable value to a dialogue box using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

sir i have got a problem with my project i calculated the sum of certain things in PHP variable say `$sum`, now i want to show its value in a dialogue box like sum of that particular things=that calculated sum using java script how will i do that?here is what i wrote,its not working what will i do?where sum1 is the variable value i want to print in the JavaScript dialogue box and size13 to size24 i calculated using some sql query .

index.php

```
<?php>   
     $sum1=$size13+$size14+$size15+$size16+$size17+$size18+$size19+$size20+$size21+$size22+$size23+$size24;
     echo '<script type="text/javascript">
     alert("Total Traffic-violation Solved During the year -2014-");
     echo $sum1;
     window.location=\'index.php\';</script>';
<?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the alert to:

```
alert("Total Traffic-violation Solved During the year -2014-'.$sum1.'");
```

Concatenate the sum into the string.

Also, you begin with <?php and end with ?>, not <?php> and <?> - or are you using a very very weird php parser?

Comment: thanx to all for the answer,andif i am using the java script in html how can i concatenate 'Total Traffic-violation Solved During the year -2014-" to the alert variable code is given below.<html>
  <head>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
 
    var js_var = "<?php echo $sum1; ?>";
         
 
    alert(js_var);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

You should use next line

```
alert("Total Traffic-violation Solved During the year -2014-'.$sum1.'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, use `$sum1` variable inside js alert() function;

```
  <?php>   
  $sum1=$size13+$size14+$size15+$size16+$size17+$size18+$size19+$size20+$size21+$size22+$size23+$size24;


  echo '<script type="text/javascript">
          alert("Total Traffic-violation Solved During the year -2014- '.$sum1.'");
          window.location=\'index.php\';
        </script>';
    ?>
```

**OR**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   alert("Total Traffic-violation Solved During the year -2014- <?php echo $sum1; ?>");
   window.location=\'index.php\';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
<?php 
     $sum1 = 50;
     echo '<script type="text/javascript">
     alert("Total Traffic-violation Solved During the year -2014-: '.$sum1.'");
     window.location=\'index.php\';
     </script>';
?>
```

Just changed your sums etc...